# UI Components not instantiating on Xamarin.IoS on Visual Studio for Mac Community when added from designer

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios

As the title says, I'm trying to add a new component in my storyboard and it works fine, but after giving it a name and heading to my controller class code behind to work with it, it always comes back as null on runtime.

I am using visual studio for mac community version 8.2.6(build 26).

Steps followed:

1. Add new storyboard
2. Add a table view controller and assign the controller class on widget properties
3. Add a picker to the table view controller and assign it a name
4. Call added picker and assign a the corresponding Model overriding ViewDidLoad()
5. Run the project

Once the program reaches step #4 and tries to assign the Model. The picker always comes as null. The same happens if I add a label or any other element, once it reaches ViewDidLoad() or any other of the life cycle methods it remains null.

I've tried cleaning, rebuilding, restaring vs, restaring the mac but none of those worked

Comment: Hi , you mean added Control not got in `ViewDidLoad()` ?

Comment: It gets into the ViewDidLoad Scope but it reaches as null @JuniorJiang-MSFT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

Went from using "storyboard.InstantiateInitialViewController()" to "storyboard.InstantiateViewController(controllerId)" and for some reason it initialized all component correctly.